# Should you recruit every trainer in Pokemon Conquest?

Tags: pokemon-conquest

In Pokemon Conquest, it seems like you have the ability to recruit around 5-7 people per town (early game). Some trainers appear to have pretty terrible stats and skills compared to others.

Is there benefit in recruiting everyone, or is better to selectively recruit only the strongest so they train faster?

Do you gain more experience when developing with less trainers on a location?

I have about 6 towns under my control and they are FILLED with trainers, and it doesn't seem like the pokemon stats improve when delegated to Develop mode. Its also a pain to move people around.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played conquest in a while but when I played I always played with the max amount of trainers and I did check to see if having less would do anything to exp I didn't really notice much of a difference so I'd say just find the strongest and use them and don't worry about the weaker ones (yes I realize this is a really late answer)